# EMOM Interval timer sound issue Swift UI

Tags: swift, timer

I am trying to create an EMOM Timer which plays a sound every minute on the minute. I have added functionality to pause the timer, reset etc.

I have been able to implement the sound to play every 60 seconds, although if the timer is paused on say 9:16, once resumed the sound will then play on 8:16 rather than 9:00 as intended.

How do I have it so the timer only sounds on each round minute regardless if the timer is paused?

Existing code;

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import AVFAudio

class EmomTimerModes: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var timerMode: EMOMTimerMode = .initial
    @Published var secondsLeft = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "timerLength")
    
    var timer = Timer()
    var soundTimer = Timer()
    
    func setTimerLength(minutes: Int) {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(minutes, forKey: "timerLength")
        secondsLeft = minutes
    }
    
    func start() {
        timerMode = .running
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in
            if self.secondsLeft > 0 && self.secondsLeft <= 3 {
                playSound(sound: "race-beep", type: "wav")
            }
            if self.secondsLeft == 1 {
                playSound(sound: "race-start", type: "wav")
                self.timer.invalidate()
                self.reset()
            }
            self.secondsLeft -= 1
        })

        // play a sound every 60 seconds
        soundTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 60.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in
            playSound(sound: "race-start", type: "wav")
        })
    }

    
    func reset() {
        self.timerMode = .initial
        self.secondsLeft = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "timerLength")
        timer.invalidate()
        soundTimer.invalidate()
    }
    
    func pause() {
        self.timerMode = .paused
        timer.invalidate()
        soundTimer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Timers are not that acccurate or reliable you can try trigger notifications

Comment: Never use a "counter" to track when something should happen if precision is important. A `Timer` is not very accurate and won't fire exactly each second. You should store a `Date` which is when the thing should occur and then when your timer fires check to see if this date has passed. You can then run your timer faster, say 0.3s, to improve accuracy. Also by using a `Date` you can use `DateComponents` to have it triggered exactly on the relevant minute (set seconds to zero) and you don't have problems with pausing.